# Connection string to SQL server with Python pypyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, database-connection, pypyodbc

I'm using this connection string but something is wrong.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect
(DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=test;UID=YYY;PWD=XXXX)
connection.close()
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Linux or macOS then you'll need to install the MS ODBC Driver, available on their website 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Then use the Driver String `{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}`

```
connection_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=..."
```

Comment: If you're on Windows, the procedure is the same actually, as the `DRIVER={SQL Server}` is a [legacy driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50041604/1026) from pre-2005 era. While it has the obvious benefit of being shipped with Windows, it's not recommended for new development.

Comment: @Nickolay I specified that this answer was only for Linux or MacOS, not Windows

Comment: and I commented that it's most appropriate for users on Windows as well...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on MacOS, firstly use homebrew to install msodbcsql:

```
brew tap microsoft/msodbcsql https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-msodbcsql
brew install msodbcsql
```

Then in Python:

If you don't have pypyodbc installed then use pip to install it:

```
pip install pypyodbc
```

Then create a Python script to connect to the db:

```
import pypyodbc as pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};"
                  "SERVER=localhost;"
                  "DATABASE=test;"
                  "UID=YYY;"
                  "PWD=XXX;"
                  "TrustServerCertificate=no;"
                  "Connection Timeout=60")
```

Comment: Getting error pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)"). Any idea what is wrong

Answer (score -1):

try this

import pypyodbc

connection = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server}; Server = servername;DATABASE=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection = Yes")

Answer (score -2):

```
import pypyodbc
connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
  'Server=localhost;'
  'Database=test;'
  'uid=YYY;pwd=XXX')
```