# Access query Like operator with parameter on linked SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-like

With native Microsoft Access tables, specifying a criterion in Query Designer as `Like [some parameter] & "*"` is no problem. I am prompted for the parameter, the asterisk is appended to the end of whatever I enter at the prompt as pattern to match, and I get a dataset satisfying the criterion.

When I try to do the same thing with linked ODBC tables (connected to Microsoft SQL Server via SQL Server driver), Access just hangs up until I kill the process. I can pass the Like operator with a string pattern (`Like "some pattern*"`) or the result of a parameter prompt (oddly, in Query Designer criterion cell, I have to express it this way: `"" & [some parameter] & ""`), but I cannot figure out how to pass the like operator with pattern and parameter together, as is possible with native Access tables (as shown above). I have tried different combinations of CStr function, Chr function, parentheses to influence order of operations, doubling up single quotes, double quotes, square brackets, etc.

To give an idea of what does and doesn't work, below is some of the things I have tried, with `[lot]` being the Access parameter. The first character is "o" for success (at least partial success), and "x" if the option did not work at all. From the results, I don't see a way to make it work.

```
xLike [lot] & "*"
xLike [lot]
oLike "*"
o[lot] & "*" empty result
o"*" Access changes this immediately to Like "*"
x[lot]
o"""" & [lot] & """" empty result
o""" & [lot] & """ empty result, no prompt for parameter
o"" & [lot] & "" shows data for lot entered
xLike "" & [lot] & ""
xLike """" & [lot] & """"
oLike "123456" shows data for lot entered
oLike 123456 Access changes this immediately to Like "123456"
xLike ([lot] & "*")
xLike CStr([lot] & "*")
xLike ([lot])
xLike CStr([lot])
oLike ("*")
oLike CStr("*")
oLike (*) Access changes this immediately to Like ("*")
oLike CStr(*) Access changes this immediately to Like CStr("*")
oLike * Access changes this immediately to Like "*"
xLike [lot] & *
oLike * Access changes this immediately to Like "*"
o* Access changes this immediately to Like "*"
o[lot] & * Access changes this immediately to [lot] & "*" empty result
xLike ([lot] & *)
xLike (CStr([lot] & "*"))
xLike CStr([lot]) & "*"
xLike CStr([lot]) & * Access changes this immediately to Like CStr([lot]) & "*"
xLike (CStr([lot]) & "*")
xLike (CStr([lot]) & *)
xLike ([lot]) & ("*")
xLike ([lot]) & (*)
xLike CStr([lot]) & CStr("*")
xLike CStr([lot]) & CStr(*)
x(Like ([lot]) & ("*"))
```

Can anyone tell me how the criterion string should be expressed in query designer, so that WHERE clause gets passed to SQL Server in the same way that `Like [some parameter] & "*"` gets passed to native Access tables? Even a tool to show what's getting passed to SQL Server would help. I am using Access 2016, SQL Server 2014, and driver SQLSRV32.dll version 10.00.10240.16384. I do not have the option of using other drivers, like SQL Server Native Client.

Comment: If you can't use a proper odbc driver for sql server 2014, use a proper sql server for the driver (e.g 2008). But why can't you use a newer driver? ODBC Admin has option to log. sql server has query log too.

Comment: Create a new query in the query designer, switch to SQL View, and paste in this query with appropriate substitutions for YourTable and YourField: `SELECT * FROM [YourTable] WHERE [YourField] Like [Lot] & ''` When you run that query does it perform as you wish?  If so, switch to Design View to see how it presents the criterion in the design grid.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher New driver cannot be used because it is beyond my control the drivers users will have installed on their computers, when they will use the Access database. Besides, any time fleet management swaps out any of their computers, they would have to acquire again the proper driver. Not impossible, but not at all preferable either.

Comment: @HansUp Query as you recommend will not work. Access hangs up like the options I've already tried.

Comment: What is the datatype of `YourField`?  Is it indexed?

Comment: @HansUp does it make sense to try using that driver with server 2014? He must upgrade driver or downgrade server or not?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Not if you're certain Stephen's problem is caused by the driver version.

Comment: Of course not certain, but I would never try that. To be safe one should use the odbc driver shipped with server as they fit to each other. @StephenFrost: maybe you can't control drivers installedm but you can check installed drivers at startup and then force them to install the proper new one or close db!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50041604/9439330 claims driver to fit only till server 2005.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Thanks for the link and suggestions. I did have to switch SQL Server datetime2 to datetime data type for backwards compatibility. Maybe I could also try replacing nvarchar with varchar for the same reason. But regardless, the link you provided makes it clear that a newer driver should be pursued somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there was no incompatibility between `Like [some parameter] & "*"` and the SQL Server or the SQL Server driver used. It was only that the query was very inefficient in its design but caused no problem until after migrating to SQL Server back end. I had one table with three left outer joins to three other tables and a where clause predicate on a column of one of the right tables (on a text column). Creating indexes on the columns involved in the join and where clause predicates did not help. What solved the problem was merely changing the left join to the table with where clause predicate to an inner join (since, effectively, that's what the where clause does to that particular relationship). After this change, the resulting data set is returned nearly instantly.

Comment: [Optimizing Microsoft Office Access Applications Linked to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/administrator/bb188204(v=sql.90)) explains that ussue,. Use Adodb, passthrough-queries or server-views, as they avoid JET/MDAC